# How can I add border to JqTree?

Tags: jquery, css, jqtree

I tried this

```
.jqtree-tree .jqtree-element {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 10px;

}
```

Probably I am missing some elements to whom this CSS should apply

Comment: provide your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like,

```
.jqtree-tree {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```